# PowerShell send email to list of addresses within another script

Tags: email, powershell, powershell-2.0, ping

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that will send an email to a list of people, but the email call is already embedded within a ping script.  This is for a system that only has PowerShell v2.0.

Computers.txt contains a list of computers to be pinged and on failure will send an email.

This is my existing script I am trying to modify:

```
Get-Content -path "E:\Computers.txt" | ForEach-Object {
if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Delay 2 -Quiet)) {
    Send-MailMessage -To "email address" -Subject "$_ is Unreachable" -Body "$_ is unreachable by ping. Next check is in 5 minutes" -SmtpServer "server address" -From "another email address"  
    } 
}
```

I know that I can use the Get-Content -path "E:\From_Email.txt" and Get-Content -path "E:\To_Email.txt" to call the list of email addresses, but I am not sure how to do this within the existing command.  I have looked online, but I have not found how to nest calling additional text files within PowerShell for a script.

Do I need to call these files earlier and set them equal to a variable which gets called?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an email address on each line of "E:\To_Email.txt", the code below should work

```
$emails = (Get-Content "E:\To_Email.txt") -join ";"
Get-Content -path "E:\Computers.txt" | ForEach-Object {
if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Delay 2 -Quiet)) {
  Send-MailMessage -To $emails -Subject "$_ is Unreachable" -Body "$_ is unreachable by ping. Next check is in 5 minutes" -SmtpServer "server address" -From "another email address"  
  }
}
```

The extra first line reads in all lines of the email list file as an array, then joins it with semi-colons, which I think is how your email addresses should be separated. Worth checking though.

Example content of "E:\To_Email.txt"

```
person.one@yourdomain.whatever
person.two@yourdomain.whatever
person.three@yourdomain.whatever
person.four@yourdomain.whatever
```

Comment: I used this script but with the -join ";" I ended up getting header errors when the email was trying to send.  I instead omitted the entire -join ";" statement and it works perfectly.  Thank you.